# make_shared performance single vs double allocation

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr

I have performed some test based on information that I read in http://www.umich.edu/~eecs381/handouts/C++11_smart_ptrs.pdf

The purpose of measurement was to check how much time consuming is single allocation and double allocation (bad style) of shared_ptr. I assume that single allocation ought to be less time consuming than double allocation.
So I would like to know if I misunderstood sth or memory allocation has no correlation with time.

The test code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


class Test{
private:
        int value;
        string name;
        double value2;
public:
        Test(int v, string n, double v2) : value(v), name(n), value2(v2){}
        ~Test(){}
};


void singleAllocation(){
        chrono::system_clock::time_point start = chrono::system_clock::now();
        for(int i = 0; i < 3000; i++)
                shared_ptr<Test> sp(make_shared<Test>(10, "This is simple test", 2.3334));


        chrono::system_clock::time_point end = chrono::system_clock::now();
        cout<<"single allocation of 3000 objects took "
            <<chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count()
            <<"us.\n";
}

void doubleAllocation(){
        chrono::system_clock::time_point start = chrono::system_clock::now();
        for(int i = 0; i < 3000; i++)
                shared_ptr<Test> sp(new Test(10, "This is simple test", 2.3334));
correlaction

        chrono::system_clock::time_point end = chrono::system_clock::now();
        cout<<"\n\ndouble allocation of 3000 objects took "
            <<chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count()
            <<"us.\n";

}


int main(){
        singleAllocation();
        doubleAllocation();
}
```

The output:
single allocation of 3000 objects took 2483us.

double allocation of 3000 objects took 1226us.

Comment: I just compiled and run your code with some more iterations (3000000). The single allocation is always faster: Single takes 1.04s, double takes 1.23s. Did you compile in Release mode?

Comment: I have compiled using: g++ --std=c++11 file.cpp -o file.out

Comment: Maybe it helps if you turn optimization on by adding `-O3` after `--std=c++11`. Unfortunately I am on windows, so I cannot try it right now.

Comment: Now I compiled with:  g++ --std=c++11 -O3 file.cpp -o file.out and got:
single allocation of 3mln objects took 244255us.
double allocation of 3mln objects took 310464us.

But when no optimalization is used, still double is faster.

Comment: @Lukasz Unless an unoptimzied case is 10x slower, it isn't an interesting change.  Unoptimized means "I don't care about speed, I want easy to walk through assembly".

Comment: Thanks Yakk, it seems clear now.

Answer (score -2):

The time cost most is constructing a string from a char*, that is "This is simple test" to a string. Delete the string member, add a optimization compiler flag, i.e. -O3, you will get what as expected.

Comment: The question is not about `std::make_shared` vs. `boost::make_shared`. It is about `std::make_shared` vs `new`.